# Python pandas: how to do operations within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "group": [1,1,1,2,2],
    "type": ["initial", "update", "update", "initial", "update"],
    "update time": ["2019-01-01 12:00:00", "2019-01-03 12:00:00", "2019-01-05 12:00:00", "2019-01-02 12:00:00", "2019-01-04 12:00:00"],
    "finish time": ["2019-01-07 12:00:00", "2019-01-07 12:00:00", "2019-01-08 12:00:00", "2019-01-05 12:00:00", "2019-01-05 12:00:00"]
    }
)

df["update time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["update time"])
df["finish time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["finish time"])

df
```

[image]

For every row, I want to calculate the difference between the 'finish time' and the 'update time' of the 'inital' row of each 'group'. As in the example, the 'finish time' can change.

The desired output is:

[image]

I guess that `groupby` is a good starting point, but I can't figure out the whole solution. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `transform('first')` to broadcast to the same shape all first values of `update time`. Then, simple subtraction

```
df['finish time'] - df.groupby('group')['update time'].transform('first')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The documentation of [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) does not explicitly say that `first`can be an input. How would I find out?

Comment: You can take as reference the [pandas series methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and pass those names as strings. `first` is one of them :) However, you usually will use `min`, `max`, `prod`, `mean`, `sum`, `first` and `last` with `transform`

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
df['finish time']-df.groupby('group')['update time'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 4):

We can using `transform`

```
df['finish time']-df.groupby('group')['update time'].transform('first')
Out[229]: 
0   6 days
1   6 days
2   7 days
3   3 days
4   3 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```